# If I have two `after_create` statements, how do I ensure that one is run before the other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two `after_create` callbacks on the same model, and the 2nd one depends on an attribute (say `client.score`) not being nil. In the first one, it runs a calculation and sets that attribute in question to some non-nil value.

But it seems that even though I have them right after each other in my model file like this:

```
after_create :callback1
after_create :callback2
```

Whenever `callback2` is run, it is still getting `client.score` to be nil.

How can I force the second one to be run after the first one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
def some_action
    callback1
    callback2
end

after_create :some_action
```

However, per the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html), your code sample should be fine too

> [Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) are generally run in the order they are defined, with the exception of callbacks defined as methods on the model, which are called last.

Comment: Btw...does it matter that the two callbacks are declared under `private` in my model?

Comment: Nope. In fact, they should be defined as private unless you want them publicly accessible outside of the class.

Comment: Yeh...this produces the same result.

Comment: It seems my issue is related to something else, and not the order the callbacks are run in.